# How do you create a Google App Engine Service?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

My employer's Google App Engine environment contains a few services. They handle different URL paths of the same domain.

I want to create an additional service, but I can't see how to do it.

I tried using the `gcloud` command line tool. You can list existing services with this command:

```
gcloud app services list
```

The `gcloud app services` command group supports `list`, `describe`, and `delete` subcommands, among others. But there is no `create`.

I went to the list of Services in the Web console. I can see all the existing services, and there is a button to delete them. But again, there is no button that I can see that creates a service.

After some Googling, which returns no answers to this question, I thought that perhaps services are dynamically created, like versions. I tried adding the name of the service, along with the desired "dispatch route", to our app's `dispatch.yaml` and deploying it. I got the following error:

```
- '@type': type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest
  fieldViolations:
  - description: Service 'new-service' does not exist.
    field: dispatch_rules
```

I'm at a loss. I can't ask the employees that created the existing services because they're gone. If Google documents how to do this, it's either buried in documentation about unrelated things, or their search engine is failing to find it.

Comment: Maybe this [guide](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/legacy/standard/python/configuration-files) though it's older.

Comment: The `service: ` tag in `app.yaml` seems to be what causes App Engine to create a service. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Remember, a service is basically a different App. It can be in a language different from other services in the project.

1. Just create a 'normal' App that will be deployed to Google App Engine. This new app will have an `app.yaml` file
2. In the `app.yaml` for your App from bullet #1, specify the name of the service i.e. add `service: <name of your service>` to the `app.yaml` file where `<name of your service>` is what you wish to call the new service.
3. Rename your `app.yaml` to `<name of your service>.yaml` or you can keep it as `app.yaml` if it's in a separate folder from your default service
4. Update your `dispatch.yaml` and add routes to your new service. See [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/legacy/standard/python/reference/dispatch-yaml) for `dispatch.yaml`
5. Redeploy the `dispatch.yaml` file and your new app